# 7 column responsive layout using Skeleton V2.0.4

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am in the process of developing an on line booking system for my business using PHP, CSS and Skeleton V2.0.4

Just about every Skeleton tutorial I have been able to find on line refers to a standard 16 column layout but V2.0.4 is a 960 wide 12 column layout. However, to display a calendar I need to produce a 7 column layout and I could use some expert help!

I last dabbled in PHP/CSS about 5 years ago and am more of a "Code Detective" than Coder, but I have been working on this for about 2 weeks now and just can not arrive at a suitable solution. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Many thanks in advance.

Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tool to create your own grid and import into skeleton: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Comment: Many thanks for your help, that is exactly what I have been looking for. Graham

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark this as the answer please?